# ffmpeg is working in terminal but not in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg using Ubuntu,

```
 sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

ffmpeg is installed on root "/usr/bin/ffmpeg".

It's working fine in the terminal, but when I execute that using php i don't get any output.

```
 shell_exec(/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i ./upload/1535531595first.mp3 -i ./upload/1535531595second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame ./download/1535531595outputnow1.mp3)
```

and using this command in "opt/lampp/htdocs/project-Name/sub-directory/test.php" file.

Any help will be appreciatable. Thanks in Advance. 
 find the attachment [cmd terminal working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nm8f.jpg) but for php not working

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to run it specifically through `shell_exec`, instead of `exec`?

Comment: @Gabriel, Thanks for revert but  I had tried exec() but always getting blank. Either using exec() or shell_exec().

Comment: You should show the complete php line and not some psuedo code so that we know it is valid php.

Comment: Have you tried putting your command to quotes? Now you have invalid PHP code. (Should be `exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg...')`)

Comment: hi @jeroen, this is the code
    $cmd = 'usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i first.mp3 -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0] amix=inputs=2:duration=longest" -c:a libmp3lame ./download/'.time().'outputnow.mp3';
 
 if(!shell_exec($cmd))
 {
  echo "audio Created!";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Error Creating audio";
 }

Comment: Missing a leading `/` in your previous comment. Was it just in your post? How about editing your initial question and providing all the details in one nicely formatted code block?

Answer (score -1):

It works everywhere perfectly! I'm using FFMPEG with my PHP project too, The most common problems are:

- Not using double quotation mark (").
- Wrong addressing.

First of all, check your path, It's better to address your file from the root directory like this `/user/foo/bar.mp3` and do the same thing for your output.

```
$input_file = "/user/foo/bar.mp3";
$output_file = "/user/foo/out.mp3";

shell_exec("ffmpeg -i \"{$input_file}\" \"{$output_file}\");
```

By the way, There is an issue with the web applications When you are using FFMPEG in your PHP project you may get the `timeout` error because it takes too much time to process.

I'd suggest you use this following script, It executes command-line commands in the background process

```
function Execute($CMD)
{
    $OS = strtoupper(PHP_OS_FAMILY);

    if ($OS == 'WINDOWS') {
        return pclose(popen("start /B {$CMD}", "r"));
    } else {
        return shell_exec("{$CMD} > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
    }
}
```